# delete log data to regain free hard drive space in oracle

Tags: linux, oracle

I have a lot of .trm and .trc files that make my hard drive full up, I don't know if I should delete it

and whether these .trm and .trc files are really important to the system

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67279698/266304) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67284411/266304)) under different accounts? Stick to one question and improve it if you don't get a helpful answer; though this isn't really on-topic for this site, as already pointed on an earlier question.

Answer (score 1):

These are trace files produced by Oracle background processes. They may sometimes contain details of system errors, but often contain nothing of immediate import. Use the adrci tool to manage them: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/automatic-diagnostics-repository-11gr1#managing-diagnostic-information

Comment: It says this is related to a .xml file, but does not specify how if deleted then delete both.

Comment: The Automatic Diagnostic Repository (ADR) contains many kinds of files, some of which are logs in xml format. Use `adrci` to purge or manage all of them. In general there is no reason *not* to delete these trace files, unless you need them for troubleshooting a specific incident.